# Trigger function if *ngIf is satisfied? angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm placing an `*ngIf` condition on one of my buttons that gets displayed if certain fields validate, it calls the `geolocation()` function on click. Instead I want to automatically trigger this function as soon as `ngIf` is satisfied. I remember using `ng-init` for this with angular 1.x, but it doesn't seem to work now nor does `*ngInit`.

```
<button *ngIf="!venueNameInput.control.valid && !address1Input.control.valid" (click)="geolocation()">Test Dojo Geolocation</button>
```

Comment: Why not create a setter for `validAddressAndVenue`, then set a watcher on the variable?

Comment: @jperezov Could you expand on the comment, not entirely sure what you have in mind. I'm trying to figure out how to use observables for this atm, something similar?

Comment: There is probably a better solution but you could always just do this: `*ngIf="!venueNameInput.control.valid && !address1Input.control.valid && (geolocation() || true)"`

Comment: [Setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) and [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) are just plain JS. Set `validAddressAndVenue` equal to `!venuNameInput.control.valid &&  !address1InputControl.valid`, then set a watcher on `validAddressAndVenue`.

Comment: @rob this calls function many times, basically keeps repeating while statement is true.

Answer (score 2):

Implement your own change detection lifecycle hook method, with some component state:

```
geoCalled = false;
...
ngDoCheck() {
    if(!this.geoCalled && this.shouldCallGeo()) {
       this.geolocation();
       this.geoCalled = true;
    }
}
shouldCallGeo() {
   return !this.venueNameInput.control.valid && !this.address1Input.control.valid;
}
shouldDisplay() { return this.shouldCallGeo(); }
```

Update your view:

```
<button *ngIf="shouldDisplay()">Test Dojo Geolocation</button>
```